# GridLayout Item Overflow flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a gridlayout with griditems being basically :
Cards
with two things :

- Image
- Text

But the image is being loaded through the internet hence sometimes it overflows the grid item box and this box does not change the height, what i want is the image should be of fixed size.

Here is my code : (How do i do it ? )

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/dbModel.dart';

class GridLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<DbModel> m;
  var appContext;

  GridLayout(this.m, this.appContext);

  Widget build(context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 7.0, mainAxisSpacing: 7.0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return GridItem(appContext, m[i]);
      },
      itemCount: m.length,
    );
  }
}

class GridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final appContext;
  final dbModel;

  GridItem(this.appContext, this.dbModel);

  Widget build(context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            dbModel.img == "NOLINK" ? Image.network("https://i.ibb.co/Vv6cPj4/404.png",) : Image.network(dbModel.img),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text("${dbModel.title}"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need wrap image widget - `Image.network` with `Expanded` & add `fit: BoxFit.cover,`.

working code:

```
Widget build(context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, //add this
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Image.network(
                "https://i.ibb.co/Vv6cPj4/404.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover, // add this
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text("Title under"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

output:

[image]

Comment: having the same problem, but when i tried to use the GestureDetector inside a column, no thing appears ?? i don not know why

Comment: how to give the custom height to the image ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Container and Inside a container declare the width and height of the image as 
you want.

```
new Container(
    width: 60.0
    height: 60.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
      image:Image.network("https://i.ibb.co/Vv6cPj4/404.png",),
      //repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
    ),
   ),
 )
```

I hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and 100% sure way to know what is going on is to specify width and height of the images yourself
for example
`Image.network('somepath', width: 200, height: 200,)`